# Refresh Parent page when closing a fancybox2 iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using an Iframe with fancybox2, to open up a page which has a form which updates a database.  What i am looking for is that when the fancybox is closed the parent page, which is a table of database results, automatically refreshes it's self.

My link to the iframe page is here:

```
   echo "<a class='fancybox fancybox.iframe' href=\"add.php?ip_address={$ip_address}&id={$id}&userna={$username1}\"  class=' btn btn-small' data-original-title='Add'>Add</a>";
```

I also have this code which i found in a different post, when i include this in the parent page, and click on the link, the fancy box starts but then immediatley closes and refreshes the page.

```
$("fancybox").fancybox({
   afterClose : function() {
    location.reload();
    return;
  }
  });
```

I have tried several re-writes of this code but it either describes as above or just doesn't work.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: check that `$("fancybox")` is actually `$(".fancybox")` in your code (you are missing a DOT unless is just a TYPO)

Answer (score 0):

try calling `window.parent.location.reload();`

Comment: Thanks, As soon as i add that to the page in the Iframe it just closes it down as soon as i click to open the iframe link and refreshes the page